# Click Button in python Using Selenium Without Id Or Using XPath

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to hit this edit button using the xpath, absolute xpath, and class name but I've had no luck.

```html
<a class="button" type="button" href="/tas/secure/hardware?action=edit&amp;unid=aff0d17eccb446e0a3c14f8ab21e307c&amp;id=52797238dc6848c1baa64958b3663774&amp;linkstructuretable=object&amp;realstructuretable=hardware&amp;componentstate=1&amp;archived=false&amp;newcomponent=false&amp;editable=false&amp;activatedtabParameter=&amp;parentContextId=c18L&amp;mangle=false">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with.

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'/tas/secure/hardware')]
```

**Edit 1:**
imports needed

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

code:

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[starts-with(@href,'/tas/secure/hardware')]")))
``
```

Comment: Still no luck i keep getting the NoSuchElementException, this website is dynamic so its making everything just that much harder.

Comment: Check with the updated answer. If that does not work then we might have to check if the element is present in the iframe.

Comment: This time i got a TimeoutException. How would I check if it's in the iframe, also sorry in still kinda new to selenium and dynamic websites.

Comment: No probs, we are always here.

Answer (score 0):

Try use css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href^="/tas/secure/hardware"]').click()
```

Or link text:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Edit').click()
```

Comment: I tried both of these and still got a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @RileyBunce Please try add wait, or check is it inside the `iframe` tag?

Comment: I already had a 10 second wait just to make sure everything had ample time to load and still no dice.